# How to make a chatbot responds in a channel only on if @chatbot?

Tags: dialogflow-es, slack

The chatbot was created in DialogFlow and integrated into Slack.
If I write in a direct message - he answers ok.
but if I add him to channel he answers on all messages.

In config Slack App for chatbot:
Subscribe to Bot Events

```
 im_created - A DM was created
 message.groups - A message was posted to a private channel
 message.im - A message was posted in a direct message channel
 message.mpim - A message was posted in a multiparty direct message channel
```

In this case
the chatbot answers in DM but doesn't answer in a channel

if to add:

```
 message.channels - a message was posted in a channel
```

the chatbot answers for all messages in DM and channel

I need to get an answer if I will write @chatbot ... on the channel.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the specifics of dialogflow, but in general a Slack bot can subscribe to the [`app_mention`](https://api.slack.com/events/app_mention) event instead of `message.channels` event.

Then your bot will only receive an event if it is mentioned, e.g. with `@chatbot`